# When and how "разбор полётов" became a idiom

Tags: этимология, выражения

In Russian "разбор полётов" means an ex post facto analysis of some event, which most likely had dramatic consequences or lead to failure.

For example:

> Дмитрий Медведев обещал провести разбор полетов в космической отрасли.

Ironically, in this context, разбор полётов have an additional connotation, due to mentioning aerospace industry.

All I know about this idiom, that is has been indeed used by aviators, but can one provide an information on why and when exactly this very phrase become a common and well known idiom?

**UPD:** Here are some hints that can help you provide a valuable answer:

- When exactly this flight analysis had existed (since I can hardly believe that each flight is analyzed nowadays), in 20-s, in 30-s in 40-s?
- When and how it became a well-known idiom. Has it  been used first, say in newspapers or, may be, in some popular TV series?

Comment: Have you seen http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2 ? There is completely answer to your question.

Comment: @hazzik, once again, I can not see an answer there in any way distinguishable from the part of the question ) See, for example, fanaguen's answer - this is kind of information that is actually valuable. See, first occurrence can be found in 1947, and this is all about actually test pilots, who were testing jet planes. In 90-s for unknown reason this idiom became more popular. See, we can get a lot of information from fanaguen's answer.

Comment: downvoter, please explain - can see nothing irrelevant to our Stack.

Comment: See wiktionary again. "Я был доволен, хотя на разборе полётов командир эскадрильи (некогда в Балашове я чуть не отчислил его от школы, потому что у него никак не выходил разворот) с неопровержимой ясностью доказал, что именно так «не следует топить транспорты». Вениамин Каверин, «Два капитана», 1938-1944 г." As you can see it was earlier than 1947

Comment: ну вот я и заапвоутил ответ - а серийные даунвоутеры кстати, системой ловятся только так)

Comment: @hazzik if you see that the question is not of a good quality - flag it or vote to close it and explain why do you think it should be closed.

Comment: @Olga I dont completely understand what you mean.

Comment: @hazzik I see from your comments that you think that the answer is very easy to find in standard sources, but you didn't flag the post and wrote comments instead. Now, you might have done it to get some explanation from the question author, why he thinks that his question is good. But I couldn't figure out from your comment, whether your intention was actually to get the more details about the question. Therefore I assumed that you want to start a discussion about the quality of the question, and it's not why comments exist.

Comment: So, I want to delete the comments, but I also want you to know, how can you act if you think that you see a low quality question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but here are some details:

According to [ruscorpora.ru](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%C2%A0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2&start=1900&end=2010&smoothing=3), this expression first occurred in 1947 in its literal meaning in an aviation-related [context](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%E0%E7%E1%EE%F0%20%EF%EE%EB%B8%F2%EE%E2&p=4&docid=50383&sid=2310).

Its use peaked [around 2003](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%E0%E7%E1%EE%F0%20%EF%EE%EB%B8%F2%EE%E2&p=1), and here it most often occurs as an idiom, sometimes with «quotes». But even the earliest modern [occurrence](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%E0%E7%E1%EE%F0%20%EF%EE%EB%B8%F2%EE%E2&p=3&docid=42295&sid=11164) in the ruscorpora uses it «with quotes», so the author assumes that the reader can infer the metaphorical meaning.

So, sadly, no clue as to who exactly made it popular in the 90s...

Comment: nevertheless this answer definitely deserves an up-vote. Thank you!

Comment: According to [this momoirs](http://militera.lib.ru/memo/russian/efimov/02.html) "analysis of flights" were performed at WW2 period.

Comment: @hazzik, now you answer is also valuable and definitely deserves an up-vote.

Answer (score 5):

This is came from USSR Air Forces. After each flight there was performed detailed flight analysis. I'm not sure when this phrase became an idiom. This phrase as many others army slangs was migrated to Russian language because USSR had compulsory military service.

---

In Russian

В ВВС СССР и теперь России, кроме боевых вылетов проводили учебные полёты. Ошибки и недочеты каждого полёта разбираются детально, чтоб в будущем их не повторять. Особенно тщательно разбираются происшествия: аварии и катастрофы. Любая авария или катастрофа тут же разбирается не только в той части, где это произошло, но и по всем полкам.

Из переписки с одним знакомым летчиком

> Аварии и катастрофы разбирались тщательно. Не только в классах, но и в
>   курилке. Потому что если причины не выяснены до конца и не усвоена
>   методика, как избежать таких случаев,значит, люди погибли зря. Поэтому
>   разбирались. Честно и дотошно, по гамбургскому счёту.

Вот, видимо нашел ответ на ваш вопрос

> Разбор полетов начал считаться основой успешного выполнения полетного
>   задания. Для разбора полетов применялись методы и приемы, от тех,
>   которые рекомендует Kamasutra, до тех, которые обязывает НПП и РОПЛОК.
>   На TV, даже журналисты стали выказывать восхищение, как в авиации
>   проводятся разборы полетов, тем самым, рекламируя оные. В обществе, и
>   особенно в Армии, после этого, разборы полетов трансформировались в
>   разборы залетов, где в основном применялась Kamasutra с
>   садомазохистским уклоном, т.к. НПП здесь не действовало. При таких
>   разборах, если не предохраняться, даже мужик мог разродиться. Простой
>   же обыватель или журналист, детально вникший в сущность разбора
>   полетов, приходил к выводу что, мы плохо летаем или не умеем летать,
>   т.к. после каждых полетов есть замечания, или разбираем одно и тоже. И
>   тогда здравомыслящее существо стало задумываться над тем, что такими
>   разборками, просто переливали из пустого в порожнее, начиная с общего
>   разбора, переходя на разборки в АЭ, звене, экипаже, и заканчивая
>   личными, на уровне совести. Но приходилось выполнять требования
>   документов, тем самым толкли воду в ступе и толчем до сих пор.
>   [источник](http://www.osobgour.narod.ru/)

Comment: USSR is a country with more than 70 years of history. When exactly this flight analysis had existed (since I can hardly believe that each flight is analyzed nowadays), in 20-s, in 30-s in 40-s? In which kind of aviation - polar, naval, etc.? Why this idiom has actually a negative connotation - do all flights has been analyzed or only one that failed? When exactly this became common - during Stalin period, at Khrushchev's era, at Perestroika? You answer is practically the same as the part of the question given.

Comment: > this phrase as many other army slangs
can you provide some examples? I can not recall much military slang in common Russian. Surprisingly, the prison slang is way more fruitful in that sense.

Comment: @shabunc just check with statistics how many people in USSR/Russia were in prisons and you will be shocked with the numbers.

Comment: I'm not shocked, I'm aware of this. You're explaining why prison slang is wide known, but you claim the same about military slang, and I can not recall much of military slang in common usage.

Comment: @shabunc on your first comment. As I say - every single flight where analysed. But flights with accident was discussing in depth and not only in classrooms but also in smoking rooms, toilets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the phrase with us since 1939.

Please skim through http://samlib.ru/c/chunihin_w_m/resh_01.shtml You can skip right to the "Чкалов" in the text.

> Приказ НКО N 070 от 4 июня 1939 года
>
> ...Число летных происшествий в 1939 году, особенно в апреле и мае месяцах, достигло чрезвычайных размеров. За период с 1 января до 15 мая произошло 34 катастрофы, в них погибло 70 человек личного состава. За этот же период произошло 126 аварий, в которых разбит 91 самолет. Только за конец 1938 и впервые месяцы 1939 гг. мы потеряли 5 выдающихся летчиков - Героев Советского Союза, 5 лучших людей нашей страны - тт. Бряндинского, Чкалова, Губенко, Серова и Полину Осипенко.
>
> Эти тяжелые потери, как и подавляющее большинство других катастроф и аварий, являются прямым результатом:
>
> а) преступного нарушения специальных приказов, положений, летных наставлений и инструкций;
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Разбор полётов.Шумиха неразбериха наказание невиновных и награждение непричастных
Армейский способ  — особая разновидность раздолбайства. Характеризуется прежде всего отсутствием конкретного виноватого, хотя практически всегда при разборе полетов таковой ответственный мгновенно назначается приказом командования. Типичное проявление — все делали то, что им приказали, исполняли и контролировали, не ошибались и не зевали, но всё вместе привело к аварии(взрыву ,потопу , проёбу).

Типический армейский способ:

Я сейчас соберу узкий круг ограниченных лиц, опираясь на которых разберусь кого следует и накажу как попало! И не посмотрю, офицер это или майор какой-нибудь!

Comment: Владимир, покажите пожалуйста, какое именно место в вопросе привело вас к выводу, что автору вопроса непонятен смысл этого выражения?

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! This is not an answer to the question. Please read our FAQ to know, what constitutes a good answer.  
Please edit your answer to make it a better fit for this site. Otherwise, we'll have to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Разбор полетов-стандартная процедура в ВВС России. Проводится обычно по факту возникновения нештатных ситуаций в полете или серии полетов. 
Собирается коллектив опытных пилотов, начальство и детально обсуждают каждое действие виновника. 
В итоге выносится решение о его виновности или не виновности.

Comment: В разговорной практике - "Устроить разбор полетов" означает Найти все ошибки или недочеты, о которых человек знает, но хочет скрыть, предать оглазке.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! This is not an answer to the question. Please read our [FAQ](http://russian.stackexchange.com/faq) to know, what constitutes a good answer.

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it a better fit for this site. Otherwise, we'll have to remove it.